# Is prescription fish oil better than over-the-counter fish oil?

Tags: alternative-medicine, nutritional-supplements

The [possible health benefits](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/druginfo/natural/993.html#References) of fish oil (primarily from its omega-3 content) have made it a [popular supplement](http://www.consumerlab.com/news/Supplement_Survey_Report/1_31_2010/).

There are a lot of over-the-counter fish oil supplements ([google fish oil](http://www.google.com/search?q=fish%20oil)) on the market and one (that I know of) that is only available by [prescription](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omacor).

Is there any scientific evidence that prescription fish oil is better (more effective, safer, other) than over-the-counter fish oil ?

Comment: According to recent studies neither work so take your pick. ;-) (Not an answer since I don’t have the studies handy.)

Comment: I had a friend who worked for the FDA who was very wary of dietary supplements, since nobody checked them to see if they contained what was on the label and nothing else.  She preferred teas, since tea is a food, and is required to be safe and properly labeled.  Therefore, the prescription stuff would at least be better regulated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better in what way?

Better because it's cheaper?  Better because it works faster?  Better because it kills less puppies?

[Some](http://www.ehow.com/facts_5941552_fish-oil-vs_-omega-3_6_9.html) [argue](http://www.mind1st.co.uk/omega-3-6-9.asp) that you should take omega 3, 6 & 9 instead of Fish oil.

The fact that a product is (or isn't) on [prescription](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prescription_drug) (in the US) only means that it has gone through [FDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Food,_Drug,_and_Cosmetic_Act) approval.

As for which is better, I'd try both for a few weeks.  Ask you better half if they notice an improvement!

Comment: "better (more effective, safer, other)" Maybe I should put that in bold.

Comment: Still, your "better" is too general.  Take Asbestos - for thousands of years it was considered the "best" product for insulation.  Only since WW2 have the hazardous affects been known / taken seriously.

Comment: I see your point. I'll have to thunk on it. Suggestions ?